# Sibling is not null, because comment counts as object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I iterate trough a list of jQuery objects and check wether the nextSibling attribute is `null`. Unfortunately a html comment counts as an sibling of type object. How can I can catch this? I need an if statement that fires for `obj.nextSibling == null || obj.nextSibling == comment`

Comment: well, you would want to use || rather than &&, and you can test nextSibling's nodeType to see what type of node it is.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Changed it to or operator, but the type of the comment  is object. So I wouldnt know if it's a div or a comment, would I?

Comment: it's an object, with properties. Nodes are objects with properties. Nodes have a `nodeType` property that is different for each type of node (tag, textnode, comment, etc)

Comment: Checking the nodeType worked, I was worried getting an error because I thought null might have no nodeType. But works good! Make it an answer an I'll mark it correct?!

Comment: "I thought `null` might have no _nodeType_" What do you mean? `null` does have no _nodeType_;  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null`

Comment: True, I got no error due to interpreter direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about writing a *function* to do it, that only returns *Elements* (i.e. `node.nodeType === 1`)

```
function nextElement(node) {
    while (node = node.nextSibling) if (node.nodeType === 1) return node;
    return null;
}
```

What this does is,

```
// while
node = node.nextSibling // get next sibling, if falsy break while
if (node.nodeType === 1) // if it is an Element, return it
// else go back to while
return null; // if we get here, next sibling was null
```

You can see a list of different values for *nodeType* [**here** on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).

Answer (score 1):

Comment nodes aren't `null`, they're comment nodes *(if they were `null` they'd make the first condition true...)*. Therefore, you need to test the `nodeType` to see if it is a comment.

```
obj.nextSibling == null || obj.nextSibling.nodeType == 8
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType

Comment: Are javascript expressions always interpreted from left to right?

Comment: Expressions yes, Operators no. For example, `5 + 4/2`(which is an expression) will result in 7 due to the order of operations (division/multiplication before addition/subtraction), however your two expressions (`obj.nextSibling == null` and `obj.nextSibling.nodeType == 8`) will be executed left to right. The right side will only be executed if the left side is false due to the `||` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to filter out comment nodes using `.filter("*")`;

Like this:

```
obj.siblings().filter("*")
```

or `obj.siblings("*")`;